# What is the right way to make a widget that changes content every 6-8 seconds ,Android

Tags: android, widget

The closest example of what i want to accomplish is the "Engadget" widget.
It updates it's data from the internet every 5-10 minutes and "scrolls" to the stories every 5-7 seconds.
I imagine it sets the 5 -10 minutes interval to the `widget's provider` to call the onUpdate without the inbuild limitations , something like that ..

```
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), updateRateSeconds * 1000, newPending);
```

Then the real issue.. to update the widgets content without calling onUpdate.

Here i imaging that inside the widget provider exists a timer or a Runnable that everytime it get's called it reschedules itself with something like that

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
...

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);
}
```

.

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {

           final long start = mStartTime;
           long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
           int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);


           int minutes = seconds / 60;
               seconds     = seconds % 60;
...

     mHandler.postAtTime(this,start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
}
```

Then on widget provider inside
`onDeleted` and `onDisabled`

i removeCallbacks `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);`

Is there anything wrong with that scheme?
Do i need to make a service to update the widget from there and keep it alive without setting an  `AlarmManager`  to the widget's configuration?
For some reason i get double calls on `onUpdate` and the runnable keeps running after i delete the widget.

Comment: Run a service that sends a broadcast that the widget listens to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). You can use it to update the data once for a set of items and then set how frequently they cycle.

Comment: is it possible to user a ViewFlipper at a widget?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout h,i cannot see a ViewFlipper anywhere here..

Comment: The documentation at that link is outdated. As of API 7 (Android 2.1) ViewFlipper is usable in widgets. (The stock News and Weather widget uses it for exactly the reason you describe.)

Answer (score 1):

Anything that runs continuously (I.E. mp3 player or radio) or requires some form of polling (alarm, SO display widget, Weather bug) should be written as a service. I know this is old but check this these vids for more info on best pratices

 http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=M1ZBjlCRfz0